# Selection.End(xlToRight) does not work

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am having a rough time getting this VBscript line to work with the excel object:

```
set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set objExcel = createobject("Excel.application") 

objexcel.Visible = true 
objexcel.Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

objexcel.Workbooks.Open dir & masterFileName 
objexcel.Activeworkbook.Worksheets("xActive_User_Ratio").Activate 
objexcel.Range("A1").Select 
objexcel.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
```

when I run this code I get an error:

```
Object required: 'Selection'
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any example would be very much helpful.

Please Help

Comment: Why are you using Select in your code? It is very rare to need it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are running this from outside Excel.

Use `objExcel.Selection` instead of just `Selection`. So that your code knows that Selection is associated with the Excel Application. Additionally, you'll need to define xlToRight or replace it with it's numerical value.

Better yet, I'd use with and rewrite the whole thing like so:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xlToRight = -4161 ' -4161 is the value of xlToRight
With objexcel
    .Visible = True
    .Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'using variables for workbook and worksheet to be explicit
    Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(Dir & masterFileName)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("xActive_User_Ratio")
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1").Select
    ws.Range(.Selection, .Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select        
End With
```

Comment: and don't forget to define xlToRight.

Comment: +1 for the key issue of *xlToRight or replace it with it's numerical value.*